# Why do I get a compilation error when I try to include an Urdu string?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, illegal-characters

I am trying to add an urdu string `غزل` as shown below:

```
class UnicodeCheck {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
   try {
    File f = new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/unicodecheck.txt");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f);
    writer.write("غزل");
    writer.close();
   } catch(Exception exc) {
       exc.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
}
```

When I try to compile the above program I get this error.

```
UnicodeCheck.java:1: illegal character: \187
∩╗┐class UnicodeCheck {
 ^
UnicodeCheck.java:1: illegal character: \191
∩╗┐class UnicodeCheck {
  ^
2 errors
```

I do not understand this error. Why do I get this and how can I get over this error?

Comment: Choose `UTF-8 charset` while saving code in .java file.

Comment: @Jayan do you realize that you changed the meaning of whole question ?

Comment: @ Suhail Gupta : sorry, I have fixed with better title. Essentially a file with unicode content is a different problem. When the same file is a java source code, fix is editor/using different encoding etc.

Comment: @Jayan what are you doing ? what is java source file  ? do you even understand what am i asking..

Comment: @Jayan now please do not make any edit to the question

Comment: @ As I understand you are adding a java source file to have some unicode strings. The error is coming from compiler not able to intepret BOM (see Sumit's answer).   The error is not a runtime one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters in the beginning of the file come from the the Byte Order Mark that some text editors like to insert into the beginning of a file. The Java compiler however does not accept files with BOM. You have two options:

1. Use a text editor that allows saving files in Unicode *without* BOM, such as Notepad++.
2. Use only ASCII characters in source code. Where you need Unicode characters use `\uXXXX`-escape codes. The JDK comes with a utility program to convert "native" text into this encoding, called `native2ascii`. For example,

   ```
   writer.write("غزل");
   ```

   would be converted into

   ```
   writer.write("\u063a\u0632\u0644");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the charset used by your Text editor (where you edit the java source file). Try to set it in `UTF-8` format.

Comment: I have already saved it in UTF-8 format. This is the reason I can see the urdu string in the .java file .